# Can I get list of all categories that foursquare API could return to me?

Tags: foursquare

Can I get list of all categories that foursquare could return to me ?

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/category.html (link to category object description)

I know that the new categories could be created, and some deleted. But I just would like to prepare my app to be able to handle some categories in special way, and I need to know in advance what they could be.

Thanks for time in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should include all possible Foursquare categories. It's this endpoint: https://location.foursquare.com/developer/reference/v2-venues-categories

Answer (score 3):

Foursquare also provides an up-to-date category hierarchy without using the API. Useful if you just want to take a look at the list without doing a call.

Interestingly on that page, they also provide "Supported Countries" where the category "can only appear on venues in those countries".

https://developer.foursquare.com/categorytree